# How to keep date data in a Struts form using html tags

Tags: java, jquery, html, jakarta-ee, struts

I´m developing a Java EE application and I'm using Struts.
When I use html tags like

```
<input size="10px"  id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text">
```

into my form, the ValidateError method (located in the FormBean class) doesn't maintain these dates after the error advise, returning and empty form.

I need to use this html tags rather than `<forms:calendar...>` (Struts  tags) because we are using jQuery framework to improve the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options :

1. You can use value=${param['start_date']} in input tag
2. You can still use struts tag and query element in jQuery using name or any other attribute.